# Getting issue to pass one controller to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 controllers

- `HomeController`
- `SearchController`

Two ViewModels

- `HomeViewModel`
- `SearchViewModel`

Two Views

- `Home`
- `Search`

Also on on my layout I am using shared `_Layout.cshtml` that defines one form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="CarrierName">Carrier Number/Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="Search" placeholder = "Carrier Number/Name" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-default">Find</button>      
}
```

When I click the button I want to be redirected to `SearchController` Index action.

My `SearchColntroller` code is:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Search)
{
    var model = new SearchViewModel();
    model.SearchText = Search;

    return View("Search", model);
}
```

My Search Page code is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchText)
```

but I am getting error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'AFS.Carrier.Web.UI.ViewModels.SearchViewModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'AFS.Carrier.Web.UI.ViewModels.HomeViewModel'.

Auppose I will be use `return view()`. It works but not work with model argument.

Kindly let me know what mistake I am doing.

Comment: Check if your view on SearchController->Index have @model AFS.Carrier.Web.UI.ViewModels.SearchViewModel

Comment: You should show all relevant code in your question. You need to show your `Search.cshtml`

Comment: on search page....i am only use this code...@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchText)

Answer (score 0):

For this code to fail, with the error you describe

```
public ActionResult Index(string Search)
{
    var model = new SearchViewModel();
    model.SearchText = Search;

    return View("Search", model);
}
```

it must be that the `Search` view does not contain a `@model SearchViewModel` statement. I would start off by making sure that the view contains that statement. Also, I would suggest that you do not place things like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="CarrierName">Carrier Number/Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="Search" placeholder = "Carrier Number/Name" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-default">Find</button>      
}
```

inside the `_Layout.cshtml` file. That file is shared among other views, so putting very specific things in it, like the BeginForm, will trip you up with the exact error that you are encountering.

I suggest you create another layout files, that uses `_Layout.cshtml` specifically for `Home` and/or `Search` if required. e.g.

_Search.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

// Search specific stuff here.
```

EDIT:

[This article about nested layouts in MVC](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/164/Nested-Layout-Pages-with-Razor) might be a good reference for you.

Answer (score -1):

check @model statement of the View of Index For SearchColntroller .
it is written like @model AFS.Carrier.Web.UI.ViewModels.HomeViewModel.
While you are passing SearchViewModel in  return View(model); statement.
Correct the model in view page. Set it to SearchViewModel instead of HomeViewModel.